# How do I add a record to a table using PHP and CURL?

Tags: php, curl, salesforce

I am using a REST API to interface a Joomla form to Salesforce.

I have successfully authenticated, and made queries, and updated existing records.

When trying to add a record however there is no result.

The code I have is this:

```
<?php

//
//  test add of a Contact
//

$data3 = array ( 'FirstName' => 'John',
                           'LastName' => 'Testing',
                           'Name' => 'John Testing' );

$data3_param = json_encode ($data3, true);

$form->data['data3'] = $data3;

$bearer =  "Authorization : Bearer ".$form->data['access'];

$hdrfields = array();
$hdrfields[] = $bearer;
$hdrfields[] = "Content-Type: application/json";                   

$url = "https://ap4.salesforce.com/services/data/v".$form->data['latestversion'];

$e = "/sobjects/Contact/";

$url2 = $url.$e;

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $hdrfields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data3_param);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response3  = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$form->data['response3'] = $response3;

?>
```

So this code is similar to the record update except that there is no record Id in the URL.  As far as I can see it follows the documentation, but obviously there is something wrong.  The three fields are the mandatory fields in the table where I want to add the record.

I hope someone can see what I have done wrong.

Thank you

Tim

Problem solved - user error.  My apologies.

Answer (score 0):

Seams you just forgot required field - AccountId. In salesforce each contact linked to some account. BTW, 'Name' field is not required, it's just calculated in SF as concatenation of first and last names.